# Reference cproj to xproj(dnx) when dnx project have packages that not suport framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, dnx

I need to have one project that is shared between .csproj and .xproj, and in my case that is Dto project between server and client (for example project1).

I have project1.csproj

I want to reference this project to project2.xproj

I am doing this by extending project.json file in project2 with:

```
 "net46": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../src/Common/project1/project1.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../src/Common/project1/obj/{configuration}/project1.dll",
        "pdb": "../../src/Common/project1/obj/{configuration}/project1.pdb"
      }
    }
```

This is not working because project2 have many librarys that don't support .Net 4.6 
What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I question this statement, but will answer it verbatim first:

> This is not working because project2 have many librarys that don't support .Net 4.6

Since the `net46` target (previously `dnx46`) is based on the full .NET Framework 4.6, how do you expect project2 to compile unless all referenced libraries are also .NET 4.6 compatible?

If your libraries are .NET 4.5.1 compatible, you could drop your target down to `net451`.

---

If instead you meant *project1.csproj has many libraries that don't support .NET 4.6*, then I would question why a DTO project needs so many libraries. Either way, you'll have to rewrite it to at **least** be .NET 4.5.1 compatible.   Could you just use POCOs and potentially remove the offending libraries?